# what are the must have applications for an intermediate devop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, web-server, monitoring

Over the past year my responsibilities have grown from managing 5 servers to 20+. Most all of these are either on EC2 or Linode and they all serve different purposes. Some are on CentOS and others on Ubuntu.

My major concern is monitoring uptime and available security updates.

It seems that every time I log into any of the servers there are atleast 10 security updates available at any given time. It worries me that one of these times I will miss a bugfix and as a result put my users in danger.

Can you recommend any applications / solutions I can use to alleviate my worries?

TLDR: Losing sleep because every time I log into my servers I see "15 updates are security updates." Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripting is important.  The language doesn't matter.

Consider a Config Management Solution.  [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) (which I know best), Puppet, CFEngine, as well as some others (Salt) are all viable.

Centralized Logging can be helpful.  Look at [LogStash](http://logstash.net/), especially if you don't want to pay for Splunk.

Performance Metrics and monitoring are vital.

Basically read all of Etsy's [Code as Craft blog](http://codeascraft.etsy.com).  [O'Reilly's "Web Operations" book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920000136.do) is also a good resource.